# Fatal Command error when using Subprocess.Run with bq load for BigQuery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, subprocess

I'm new to python, and i'm trying to ingest a CSV file in Bigquery, using subprocess.run and the bq load util.

If I write the same command in a shell (windows), it works like a sharm. But when I try to use it in python, I get an error.

This is the code I'm using:

```
# run() returns a CompletedProcess object if it was successful
# errors in the created process are raised here too

command= r'load --project_id=the_projectid_goes_here --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1 DataSet.TestTable gs://bucket/folder1/folder2/File.csv C:\Users\Username\Folder\File.json'

process = subprocess.run(['bq', command], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And this is the error:

```
FATAL Command 'load --project_id=the_projectid_goes_here --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1 DataSet.TestTable gs://bucket/folder1/folder2/File.csv C:\Users\Username\Folder\File.json' unknown
Run 'bq.py help' to get help
```

Any idea about what is the trouble?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I pass the same command but as a list, it works:

```
comma3=[]
comma3.append(r'--project_id=the_projectid_goes_here ')
comma3.append(r'--source_format=CSV ')
comma3.append(r'--skip_leading_rows=1 )
comma3.append(r'DataSet.TestTable ')
comma3.append(r'gs://bucket/folder1/folder2/File.csv ')
comma3.append(r'C:\Users\Username\Folder\File.json')

process = subprocess.run(['bq','load',comma3], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```